# Returning a list of directories with NSMetadataQuery and NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nspredicate, icloud

I'm trying to get a list of directories in the user's iCloud folder. I worked out how to look for special types of files (such as txt files) and it works fine:

```
NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
_query = query;

//Search all files in the Documents directories of the application’s iCloud container directories:
[query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]]; 

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K ENDSWITH '.txt'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];

[query setPredicate:pred];
[query startQuery];
```

However, I'm now trying to get only directories. I've read through the docs concerning [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html), but I have no clue how to go about looking for directories. I guess NSPredicate is not made for this? I can check if something is a directory like this:

```
    BOOL isDir;
BOOL exists = [fm fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir];
if (exists) {
    /* file exists */
    if (isDir) {
        /* file is a directory */
    }
 }
```

But how to apply this to a NSMetadataQuery, I have no clue. I'd be grateful for any help I can get.

---

EDIT:

I changed the predicate to `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.pathExtension = ''", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];`

I then determine when the query is finished like so:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];
[query startQuery];

- (void)queryDidFinishGathering:(NSNotification *)notification {

NSMetadataQuery *query = [notification object];
[query disableUpdates]; // You should invoke this method before iterating over query results that could change due to live updates.
[query stopQuery]; // You would call this function to stop a query that is generating too many results to be useful but still want to access the available results.

[self loadData:query];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];
_query = nil; // we're done with it

}
```

And finally, I do a count, but this will always give me 0 however many directories I have in the cloud (I checked this via Lion and the Mobile Documents folder; e.g. I have Documents/myTXTs etc.). This is very strange. If I do a count on the text files, it will give me 4 as I have 4 txt files. So I guess my directories are not being counted:

```
 - (void)loadData:(NSMetadataQuery *)query {

    NSLog(@"Query count %i", [query resultCount]);

...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried EmptyStack's answer without luck....

I've found that **`NSMetadataQuery` does NOT find directories**, The problem is not the `NSPredicate` is filtering directories from the results, the problem is simply the query don't find folders. I've tried with the debugger and found that all `LBItem`s found, are of regular files not directories. I hope Apple improves this in the future. 
<strike>Maybe in MountainLion this is better since they seem to have folder support ... oops off course you didn't read this here because it's still NDA. Forget it</strike>

However there is at least one **way of working-around this:**

For example if your file structure is;

```
|_Folder
| |_file
| |_file2
|_Folder1
| |_file
|_file
```

and we make a query with predicate:

```
predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE '*'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey
```

results will be (use `NSMetadataItemURLKey` to get the URL)

```
path/to/iCloud/Documents/Folder/file
path/to/iCloud/Documents/Folder/file2
path/to/iCloud/Documents/Folder1/file
path/to/iCloud/Documents/file
```

What we need to do is to filter these results by ourselves by looking at the number of components of each URL and chopping URLs as needed. Items at the first level should have `numberOfComponentsOfUbiquitousContainer + 1`, next level would have even one more and so on.
We need to discard repetitions too (or like in this example we will get `Folder` twice).

Probably not optimal but works for me,

#### Update:

Better use below predicate, it reduce query results when crawling sub folders.

```
// dirPath is an NSString path of the directory you want
// to look at. Usually, for the top level directory:
// [NSFileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil].path;
predicateWithFormat:@"%K BEGINSWITH %@", NSMetadataItemPathKey, dirPath];
```

Comment: :I used
predicateWithFormat:@"%K BEGINSWITH %@", NSMetadataItemPathKey, dirPath];
But I not giving all the folder. Can you tell me how you did this?
I also want to show all the directories and files from icloud account.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get only the directories use the following predicate.

```
predicateWithFormat:@"%K.pathExtension = ''", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey
```

Note that, this doesn't guarantee that you will get only the directories by using this method as there are (I've seen some) files which has no extensions. But if you are sure that all your files has extensions then you can very well use this.

If you want to get all the files regardless of their extension, just add the NOT keyword to the above predicate,

```
predicateWithFormat:@"NOT %K.pathExtension = ''", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey
```

Comment: Thanks. I did a  NSLog(@"Query count %i", [query resultCount]); but it doesn't show any results even though there are two directories. It finds all the txt files, but not the directories. Is there a way to list ALL files, regardless their extension or ending?

Comment: If you want all files change the predicate to this `@"NOT %K.pathExtension = ''"`

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't list my directory. I checked if it is really there by going to Mobile Documents in Lion. The folder is called myTXTs and even if I change the predicate to predicateWithFormat: @"%K == %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, @"myTXTs" the count will return 0. Any ideas? It appears as if the directory is simply not there - despite being there!

Comment: I updated my code above - perhaps I'm doing something wrong when counting the query. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with MDQuery - which is the 'real' code that NSMetadataquery uses.

In Terminal, type 'mdls' then drag in a folder. Then type mdfind and use the provided example only change the kMDItemContentType type tree to public.folder - you will get lots of results.

Then to do this in code, you need to follow an MDQueryRef example. The code flow is identical to the Cocoa stuff, and I find the queries much easier to create and understand. You can set cocoa callbacks to the MDQuery - so its pretty well drop in compatible with NSMetadataquery.

NSMetadataQuery has some iCloud stuff that I don't think is in MDQuery. So they are not identical, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately "Metadata framework" is not available in iOS SDK (as of iOS6). **iOS provides only the Objective-C metadata search interface. The procedural C version is only available on OS X.**

Which means we, 3rd party devs, must use NSMetadaQuery, NSMetadataItem, etc and not their low level counter parts MDQuery, etc
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/Introduction.html

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
[query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like '*.txt'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey]];
```

It works for me.

Comment: It looks like this would return a list of text files, not directories, wouldn't it?