# iCloud: How to read in directories created by the user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nspredicate, icloud

I would like to read in a list of all directories that are created either by the user or the app in iCloud's Mobile Documents directory (the one found in Lion under ~/Library/Mobile Documents). Here is an example of how this directory could look like:

[image: iCloud's Mobile Documents]

I tried the following code, but the query I run will not contain any objects representing my folders (using the NSPredicate `predicateWithFormat:@"%K.pathExtension = ''", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey`). If I run a query for txt files (using `@"%K ENDSWITH '.txt'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey`), I will get 5 objects returned for the txt files respectively. Looking for txt files thus works, but not for directories. Reading through the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/CreateCustomDocument/CreateCustomDocument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH8-SW1), I noticed that Apple suggests to use NSFileWrapper (File Packages) instead of directories.  Is iCloud not able to handle/detect directories created by the user or the app?

Here is my code:

```
-(void)loadDocument {

    NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
    _query = query;
    //Search all files in the Documents directories of the application’s iCloud container directories:
    [query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]]; 

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.pathExtension = ''", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];

    [query setPredicate:pred];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];
    [query startQuery];
}

- (void)queryDidFinishGathering:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSMetadataQuery *query = [notification object];
    [query disableUpdates]; // You should invoke this method before iterating over query results that could change due to live updates.
    [query stopQuery]; // You would call this function to stop a query that is generating too many results to be useful but still want to access the available results.

    [self loadData:query];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];
    _query = nil; // we're done with it
}


- (void)loadData:(NSMetadataQuery *)query {

   NSLog(@"Query count %i", [query resultCount]);

    for (int i=0; i < [query resultCount]; i++) {
        NSMetadataItem *item = [query resultAtIndex:i];
        NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
        NSLog(@"%i.URL: %@", i, url);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at "Manage Storage" in the iClouds Settings in Mac OS X Lion. When I click my application, it will only show the different txt files (plus conflicting versions) and no directories whatsoever. So I have to assume that you can only work with wrappers / file packages but not with directories.

Comment: Did you ever work-arounded this? For what it worths, in Mountain Lion users are able to create folders from the Open panel inside the app. Have you tried `NSMetadataQuery` API in there? That should give us a hint how this is changing in iOS ...

Comment: @nacho4d no, in the end I did not go with folders, sorry. As you say, this may change with M Lion. Keep me posted if you find a way.

Comment: Just for the record (because I think you already noticed) I posted a work-around here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873974/returning-a-list-of-directories-with-nsmetadataquery-and-nspredicate/10510752#10510752